# python to write directly to S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a python function that prints some stuff. I am gonig to put that to AWS Lambda and would like to print these stuff directly to a file in S3 bucket. 
So something to redirect stdout in S3 bucket file.
This is how I call the fuction:

```
recurse_for_values(top_vault_prefix, top_level_keys)
```

Comment: You use the boto3 put_object() method to write objects to S3 (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object). It can put files as well as a raw string of bytes.

Comment: So can I do something like:  response = client.put_object(Body=recurse_for_values(top_vault_prefix, top_level_keys), Bucket='my_bucket_name')

Comment: If recurse_for_values() returns an array of bytes, then yes. Give it a try, write some code. You'll also have to include the object Key in your call to put_object().

Answer (score 4):

Almost the same as Thomas L., but with io so that you don't actually write any file locally (everything is in memory).

```
import io
import tinys3
f=io.StringIO(u"some initial text data")
conn = tinys3.Connection('yourAccessKey', 'yourSecretKey', tls=True)
conn.upload('yourS3Key', f, 'yourBucketName')
f.close()
```

OR

you could use something like S3FS (https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount your S3 bucket as a disk and then simply redirect the output as you would do for a local disk, but I heavily discourage this option. S3 is definitely not a filesystem and shouldn't be used as such. For example it generates loads of requests to S3 (and thus costs) and may not be that reliable...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your logs to a local file and then synchronise it with AWS S3 at the end of your script.

```
import tinys3

log_file_object  = open(“logfile”, “w”)
log_file_object.write("Some logs...")
log_file_object.write("Some other logs...")
log_file_object.close()

conn = tinys3.Connection('S3_ACCESS_KEY','S3_SECRET_KEY',tls=True)
conn.upload('log_file_DDMMYYYY',f,'my_bucket')
```

You can also use boto3 to update your file but tinys3 is easier to use for tiny usage.
Hope it can help.

Comment: Creation of local files is what I wanted to avoid as these are passwords...